# Not able to display Google map

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, microdata

This is javascript function to access latitude longitude and city from json:

```
function parse()
{
var json = '<?php echo $json; ?>';
var events = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
var DateArray = new Array();
var size = Object.keys(events).length;
search(events);
}
 function search(events)
 {
  for ( i in events)
 {
if( typeof events[i] === 'object' )
{
 key= i.toLowerCase();
      if(key.indexOf("latitude") !== -1)
      {
      var lat = events[i];
      var longi = events['longitude'];
       // alert(lat + longi);
           initialize(lat,longi,'5');
          // DateArray = DateArray.concat(events[i]);
          // alert('DataArray');
       }
          search(events[i]);   
 }
 }
  }
```

I have this json:

```
{
   "type":"http://schema.org/Place",
   "class":"place",
   "city":"London",
   "geo":{
       "type":"http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates",
       "class":"geocoordinates",
       "latitude":"30",
       "longitude":"70"
    }
}
```

map code:

```
function initialize(a,b,zom){
    if (!a || !b ||!zom){
          var centerLoc=new google.maps.LatLng( 34.61701054652337,71.37824736488983);
          zoom=16;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(typeof a + typeof b + typeof zom);
        var zoom =parseInt(zom);
        var centerLoc=new google.maps.LatLng(a,b);
        alert('it works fine');
    }
       var mapProp = {
            center:centerLoc,
            zoom:zoom,
            //mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
       };
       var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap") ,mapProp);
       marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                  position:centerLoc,
                  title:'Click to zoom'
             });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
                map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
       });
            marker.setMap(map);
}
       google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(window, 'load', initialize);
```

When lat long and city are initialized, initialized function is called with lat and long as parameters.

**problem**

When arguments are passed to initialize function to initialize google map, it shows that function is called as it alerts the values of parameters in called function.lat and long both are string of type as required. but this does not show google map.

Comment: [works](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_initialize.html) for me.

Comment: then why not for me ? :(

Comment: Why?  It is a working link. You provide a jsfiddle or a link that _doesn't_ work (exhibits the problem you are asking about)?

Comment: here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bariha/YZaYs/1/)

Comment: [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Nfkmp/)

Comment: gives error Page not found on click to save.

Comment: so don't click on save

Comment: main problem is with that save button. i have to display map on click to that button.

Comment: the save button is a submit-button, when you wan't to display a map don't use a button that submits the form(unless you're working with the submitted data, what currently doesn't happen)

Comment: then what else i can use?

Comment: preview button is also submit button but it displays map on click

Comment: the preview-button is not a submit-button https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2FInput#attr-type

Comment: changed its type to button and it works.thank you thank you sooo much :)